# How to get the first cell value of selected row of a gridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: error while using cells]

I have Gridview with several columns. When I select particular row of gridview, I am not able to get the value of first cell. Its showing following error.

Error   15  'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 3):

You must do

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ... )
```

You have a wrong type in your iteration variable.

Comment: I did that                     foreach (DataGridView row in gvViewCustomer.SelectedRows) but getting the same error

Comment: Look again at what I've posted. It's DataGridViewRow row instead of DataGridView row.

Comment: @noushadmohammed No problem.

Comment: @noushadmohammed When you find a post as your answer (Mihai's asnwer) you can kindly accept the answer and when you find a post helpful you may kindly vote it up :)

Answer (score 1):

Mihai Caracostea Showed your problem correctly.
Just to learn how to work with selected row(s) please consider these notes:

- If you want only one row could be selected, set `MultiSelect` yo `false`
- Check `yourGrid.SelectedRows.Count==1`if you want to check if there is a selected row
- When you want to read selected row values, first check if there is selection then use `yourGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[index of column]` or `yourGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[nam of column]`